# count letters using javascript until you obtain a specific number

Tags: javascript

I need you help with a js.
I have a textbox, and i have already wrote a script to detect how many letters are in each textbox (for example, into the word "hello" there are 1H - 1E - 2L -1O)

```
$(function () {
        var text = $('#testWords').text(); 
        var hCount = text.split('h').length - 1;          
        var eCount = text.split('e').length - 1;
        var lCount = text.split('l').length - 1;           
        var oCount = text.split('o').length - 1;            

        $('#output').html(
            'words count:
             </br>H - ' + lCount +             
            '</br>E - ' + oCount +             
            '</br>L - ' + vCount +
            '</br>O - ' + vCount});
```

and so i have the number 1120 obtained from the count of the letters.
What i need is to sum the letters in this way:

- 1120 (hello letters result number)

(1+1) - (1+2) - (2+0)

(H+E) - (E+L) - (L+O)

I know that i could add a simple sum using the js syntax, but the problem is that i need to keep sum untill i remain only two numbers, for example if i have this numeric code here:

> 126876

the sum will be

> 1+2 - 2+6 - 6+8 - 8+7 - 7+6
>
> 3 - 8 - 14 - 15 - 13 (results)

so the next sums are

> 3+8 - 8+1 - 4+1 - 5+1 3

splitting the double number into single ones and so on untill all the sum result are only a number from 0 to 99

I hope that i explained my problem in an easy way, and that someone could help me with this.

And also, if someone as some advice or improve for the code that i've done, please let me know.

thanks a lot
cheers

Maybe to make it easy, i need to split a number like 88 into 8 and 8 and then sum the last one with the first one after and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is something that I don't understand in your code: How do you get to `1120` from `hello`? There should never be a 0, that should be 1121 if I understand your logic correctly.

That being said, I did give it a shot and this is what I came up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/75fyZ/3/

As you will notice I optimized your code a bit (that split thing is really ugly, and it produces wrong results). The full code (including some helpers and the interface logic) is on the fiddle, but the main logic is here:

```
function calculateMagicNumber(text) {
    // count the chars - return s something like {'h':1,'l':2,'o':1}
    var charCounts = countCharOccurances(text);

    // replace each char by its count
    var digits = '';
    for (var l = 0; l < text.length; l++) {
         digits += charCounts[text[l]];
    }

    // do the magic sum, until only 2 digits left
    var i = 1;
    while (digits.length > 2) {
        digits = sumAdjecentDigits(digits);

        // prevent an infinte loop
        i++;        
        if (i > 20) return false;
    }

    return text;
}
```

If you start playing with it, you will notice that the numbers can start growing quite quickly. A few samples:

- test: 5 cycles -> 68
- lorem ipsum: 20 cycles -> 181265311222213119191055129159163315... (more then 500 digits)

So that is why I added the 'infinite loop' protection. Even with a guard at 100 cycles my browser crashed...

So one more question, for you. Besides being a fun experiment, **why would you ever need an algorithm like this?**

I hope you like the result I came up with. Feel free to ask if anything is not clear, or if I misunderstood any of the specs.